# Swift NSManagedObject is empty

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobject

Guys I have a huge issue and though I did find something about it, the solution was kinda old and it involved Objective-C code, which doesnt help me very much as I need a Swift solution. 
 The issue I'm facing is that if I try to create a NSManagedObject and set a property, when trying to print it (or save it) it is just blank. The fetch functions shows only empty values in the array something like this ([,,,,,]) 
The code for saving is this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

var error: NSError?
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Currency", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

var currency = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext) as Currency
currency.symbol = "EUR"
println(" currency is \(currency)")`
```

While the one for fetching is :

```
if !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.description)")
}
else {
    println("saved")
    println("\(currency)")

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Currency")
    let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [Currency]

    println("\(fetchedResults)")

}
```

I would really really appreciate any help as this is starting to drive me insane. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help someone else, the actual issue is with the println. 
As it turns out, you can't use println for a NSManagedObject, you have to use NSLog...
 So the array was not empty, it's just a bug with println that doesnt know how to output the data!